# Outlook 2013 email proofing

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2013, proofing

My proofing checks way too much.  I just want it to proof my email and the title.  The way it is set right now, it checks the previous email and all of the email addresses.  How can I turn that off?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent it. That is the way it is by design. You can set it in Outlook so previous messages are attached instead of inline, this would accomplish what you want or you can just not include previous messages.

Another way around the issue would be to type the message up in Word first then copy and paste.